# set Default date in datepicker with Tuesdays & Wednesdays only?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, datepicker

I have a datepicker that has all past days disabled, and all days except Tuesdays and Wednesdays disabled.

I'd like the default day to be the frist enabled day of the week.  If it's tuesday, then it should display tuesday,  If wednesday, then wednesday.  Any other day it should display next tuesday in the input field.

This is the code I'm using for the datepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
            minDate:'0',
            changeMonth:true,
            changeYear:true,
        beforeShowDay:
              function(dt)
              {
                  return [dt.getDay() === 2 || dt.getDay() === 3, ""];
              }});
        });
</script>
```

And the input that I'm using the selector on:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div style='margin:0 auto; text-align:center;'>
        <label>Appointment Date: </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="list_appointments" />
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" class="datepicker" />
               <!--value=--><?php #echo date_format(new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago')),'m/d/Y');?> 
        <input type="submit" value="Refresh List" name="Update" />
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to make getting the next day of the week a little easier and then just have a if-else statement to get the correct day of the week:

```
 function setDate() {
   var today = moment().isoWeekday(); //or just = new Date().getDay();
   if (today <= 2) {
     return moment().isoWeekday(2);
   } else if (today === 3) {
     return moment().isoWeekday(3);
   } else {
     return moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(2);
   }
 }
```

Call the `setDate()` function then and set that return value as the date in the datepicker.

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date(setDate()));
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jutcw0ve/

Comment: `new Date().getDay()` is not equivalent to ISO weekday numbering as it returns `0` for Sunday, however `var isoWeekday = new Date().getDay() || 7;` will give the correct result. ;-)

Comment: The setDate Method you defined correctly returns a timestamp, but the timestamp won't set the date in the selector statement for me.

Comment: @ArmorCode, did you make sure to set it exactly as I did in the above code? (Note, you need to do `new Date(setDate())` as I did otherwise it doesn't work).

Comment: Yes.  I also verified that the function was producing the correct value with `document.write()` and tried saving the moment statments to a variable, and then tried returning `new date(momentVariable)` and putting `setDate()` as the second parameter in the selector for `.datepicker`  With those changes, it still produced the right value, but did not show up in the datepicker.  Does the arguement need to be correctly formatted?  as m/d/Y as the datepicker is?