# jquery class selector function won't accept date as arguement

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I'm using a function that successfully calculates and (should successfully) return the date for Tuesday if today is Tuesday, Wednesday if it's Wednesday, and if it's some other day today it should return next Tuesday.  This function is used to put this date into put into a datepicker input's default value.  I've verified that the function does in fact calculate the correct date to use.  However, when passing the return value to the selector's arguements, no date is displayed in the input object.

I tried entering strings and numbers into the second argument of the selector function instead of setDate() and it still doesn't display anything.

For a history of what led to this question, you can reference this question [Original question that led to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836245/set-default-date-in-datepicker-with-tuesdays-wednesdays-only)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>My Title</title>
    <!-- for datepicker -->
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- for timepicker -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <!-- for momentjs -->    
    <script src="//momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"/></script>
    <script src="//momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
                minDate:'0',
                changeMonth:true,
                changeYear:true,
            beforeShowDay:
                  function(dt)
                  {
                      return [dt.getDay() === 2 || dt.getDay() === 3, ""];
                  }});
            });

        // function moment().isoWeekday is from Momentjs script source above.
        // to automatically set the date to the next tuesday or wednesday if not already one of those days.
        function setDate() {
            var today = moment().isoWeekday(); //or just = new Date().getDay();
            var timestamp;
            if (today <= 2) {
                timestamp = moment().isoWeekday(2);
            } else if (today === 3) {
                timestamp = moment().isoWeekday(3);
            } else {
                timestamp = moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(2);
            }
            document.write(new Date(timestamp));
            return new Date(timestamp);
        }
        // Problem occurs here: it's like setDate() wont' give datepicker something it can display.

        $('.datepicker').datepicker("setDate", setDate());            


        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
                timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
                interval: 90,
                minTime: '9',
                maxTime: '10:30am',
                defaultTime: '9',
                startTime: '9:00',
                dynamic: false,
                dropdown: true,
                scrollbar: false                
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST">
  <div style='margin:0 auto; text-align:center;'>
    <label>Appointment Date: </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="list_appointments" />
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" class="datepicker" />
    <input type="submit" value="Refresh List" name="Update" />
    <br />
  </div>
</form>
<body>
```

Comment: Don't use document.write, if called after the page has finished loading it will erase the whole page before writing

Comment: @PatrickEvans Noted.  This problem still occurs though,  I'm just using it as a debugging device.

Comment: Doesn't work because you are calling that outside of a ready callback, the element doesn't exist yet when you make that call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you need. Remember to keep your function calls within the same document load function, i.e. $(document.ready).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
                minDate:'0',
                changeMonth:true,
                changeYear:true,
                beforeShowDay: function(dt)
                  {
                      return [dt.getDay() === 2 || dt.getDay() === 3, ""];
                  }
            });

            $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
                timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
                interval: 90,
                minTime: '9',
                maxTime: '10:30am',
                defaultTime: '9',
                startTime: '9:00',
                dynamic: false,
                dropdown: true,
                scrollbar: false                
            });

            function setDate() {
                var today = moment().isoWeekday(); //or just = new Date().getDay();
                var timestamp;
                if (today <= 2) {
                    timestamp = moment().isoWeekday(2);
                } else if (today === 3) {
                    timestamp = moment().isoWeekday(3);
                } else {
                    timestamp = moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(2);
                }
                return new Date(timestamp);
            }

            $('.datepicker').datepicker("setDate", setDate());          
        });

        // function moment().isoWeekday is from Momentjs script source above.
        // to automatically set the date to the next tuesday or wednesday if not already one of those days.

        // Problem occurs here: it's like setDate() wont' give datepicker something it can display.     
    </script>
```